# SQL Reporting Services 2005 - Access by Active Directory Security Group

Tags: reporting-services

Is there a way to lock down the security of a SSRS report by AD group?
I need to make it so "Group A" has access and "Group B" does not.
The connection string to the database needs to remain a single SQL Server account.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I don't have SSRS sitting open in front of me, but the default security model for SSRS is Integrated Windows Security.  So you basically just go into the SSRS admin console (the http://server/reports site) and set the security on a specific report to just Group A (with Read Access) and no one else will have access to it